# Jasmine Karma test fails on Jenkins

Tags: angular, jenkins, karma-jasmine

I am new to JENKINS and Angular. I am using maven as a build tool. I am trying to run jasmine test cases in maven test phase using `karma.conf.js`. Test cases are working fine on local but not working on jenkins.

Executing Karma Test Suite ...

```
/jenkins/workspace/projectName/web/some-service/src/test/resources/node_modules/.bin/karma start /jenkins/workspace/projectName-pipeline/projectName/web/some-service/src/test/resources/karma.conf.js --single-run
```

I am getting following error:

> /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

I checked the environment variables as well and found Node is in the path.

Comment: How do you access the env variable? Can you share the code?

Comment: In jenkins i executed a sh file.. where i printed all the environment variables